# How to open Nautilus (File Manager) preferences in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, nautilus

Please could you tell me where can I find the File Manager Preferences in Ubuntu 13.04.
I want to run a sh file.

Comment: Voting to re-open as existing answer is out of date.

Comment: Up to date answer regarding Nautilus preferences is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/861333/how-to-open-nautilus-file-manager-preferences/865124#865124)

Answer (score 5):

Open **Files -> Preferences** in the menu bar.
In the preferences dialog, you find the option for running shell files under the tab **Behavior -> Executable Text Files**:

[image]

Comment: the Files menu do not appear in File Manager I am at xubuntu 16