# Changing sortorder in Gnome 3 nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 17.04

I am trying to get a grib on the new Ubuntu based on the Gnome 3 desktop so:
How do I change the sortorder in Nautilus, so I have a list with folders first then files?[image]
Where do I find Proberties or View ??

In the Settings menue Filemanager is missing too!

The proberties option gives these options, which we have seen from every proberties of files and folders on the desktop and elsewhere[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTWpO.png)

Comment: I can see a **Properties** option in the pop-up menu in your screenshot, 4th from the bottom. If you just want to sort folders before files, then run `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences sort-directories-first true` in Terminal.

Comment: @pomsky   Yes but that is just the proberties of the file, like rights and such, see edit!

Comment: I see. Click on the title/location next to *Activities* (Files/ Rhythmbox in your screenshots) in the top-bar. There's a **Preferences** option in the drop-down menu. I guess that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to Karel and Pomsky for keeping me searching!  See this link!

[How to open Nautilus (File Manager) preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861333/how-to-open-nautilus-file-manager-preferences)

Wonder why I couldnt find this!

So In the Tweak Tool go to Top Bar ( see pics )[image]
But you have to turn **Show Application Menu** OFF not on to get access to the settings menue (see top left corner just before the looking glass)
This must be an error, but is it in Nautilus or Tweak?