# Remove date in desktop icons' name

Tags: 18.04, desktop-environments, date, filename, desktop-icons

How to remove date (most probably the last modified date) from the desktop icons' name?

[image]

I tried renaming it but the date still does not go. I have dragged the folder from nautilus to desktop. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch *Files* (aka Nautilus) and click on the "*Files*" button next to "*Activities*" and select **Preferences**.

Change all the entries (*First*/*Second*/*Third*) under "*Icon View Captions*" to **None**.

[image]

Comment: I am not seeing any _"Files"_ or _"Activites"_ button.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis What's your Ubuntu flavour? Not the standard vanilla Ubuntu? Could you post a screenshot of your whole desktop?

Comment: Normal Ubuntu Desktop which I downloaded a few days ago. But I have installed the mac theme. I also tried (this)[https://askubuntu.com/q/861333/827936]. I'll post the screenshot shortly.

Comment: Screenshot of "Files" application: https://imgur.com/a/T1P3e5F

Comment: Screenshot of Desktop: https://imgur.com/a/k4aGnAT

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis See in the second screenshot there is a "Screenshot " button in top bar. You'll see a "Files " when you have opened Files application. Click on that "Files " button and select "Preferences", that's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Can you add the last comment to your answer so that I can accept it?