# Weird file sorting

Tags: 18.04, directory

For some weird reason my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS laptop is now showing files *and* folders in the following order:

1. folder A
2. file A
3. folder B
4. file B
5. folder C
6. file C

I'm pretty sure its always been folders first and then files and I'd really like it sorted that way. I've done a bit of searching but haven't found the answers. So what I'd like is

1. folder A
2. folder B
3. folder C
4. file A
5. file B
6. file C

Why has this changed and how can I reset it?

Comment: So, what command are you running ?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using "*Files*" a.k.a *Nautilus*:

Go to Preferences -> Views and enable `Sort folders before files`:

[image: Sort files before files]

Comment: Super thank you !! For anyone wondering where this is - please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/861333/how-to-open-nautilus-file-manager-preferences